# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I am upgrading ActiveMQ4.0 and Jboss4.0 to AMQ5.4.3 and Jboss5.1.0 respectively. Current JDK version is 1.5.
When i make a soap request call from SoapUI console,for some of the services, getting below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2326)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1336)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1910)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1834)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:184)
    at com.netratings.ds.esb.impl.transport.jms.JmsEndpointImpl$JmsEndpointListener.onMessage(JmsEndpointImpl.java:67)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1229)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:134)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:205)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:651)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:676)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

This error occurs suddenly after a large number of iterations and only for few of the SoapUI calls. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to the error. But the error is occuring only when the call enters the message synchronizer section.

This is my ActiveMQ.xml file

> ```
> <beans
>   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>   xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
>   http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
>
>     <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
>     <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
>         <property name="locations">
>             <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
>         </property>      
>     </bean>
>
>     <!-- 
>         The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker. 
>     -->
>     <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data"
> ```
>
> destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true">
>
> ```
>         <!--
>           For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
>           For more information, see:
>
>             http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html
>
>             Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer flow control.
>             For more information, see:
>             http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
>         -->
>
>         <destinationPolicy>
>             <policyMap>
>               <policyEntries>
>                 <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
>                   <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
>                     <vmCursor />
>                   </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
>                 </policyEntry>
>                 <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
>                   <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
>                        For more information, see:
>
>                        http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html
>
>                   <pendingQueuePolicy>
>                     <vmQueueCursor/>
>                   </pendingQueuePolicy>
>                   -->
>                 </policyEntry>
>               </policyEntries>
>             </policyMap>
>         </destinationPolicy> 
>
>
>         <!-- 
>             The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in 
>             JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by 
>             the JVM. For more information, see: 
>
>             http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html 
>         -->
>         <managementContext>
>             <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
>         </managementContext>
>
>         <!-- 
>             Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
>             mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag). 
>             For more information, see: 
>
>             http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html 
>         -->
>         <persistenceAdapter>
>             <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
>         </persistenceAdapter>
>
>
>           <!--
>             The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will 
>             use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
>
>             http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
>
>         <systemUsage>
>             <systemUsage>
>                 <memoryUsage>
>                     <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
>                 </memoryUsage>
>                 <storeUsage>
>                     <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
>                 </storeUsage>
>                 <tempUsage>
>                     <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
>                 </tempUsage>
>             </systemUsage>
>         </systemUsage>
>       -->
>
>         <!-- 
>             The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
>             clients and other brokers. For more information, see: 
>
>             http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html 
>         -->
>         <transportConnectors>
>             <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
>         </transportConnectors>
>
>     </broker>
>
>     <!-- 
>         Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
>
>         Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details 
>     -->
>     <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
>
> </beans>
> ```

This error was not occuring for AMQ 4.

Any help in resolving this issue is highly appreciated.